# How to insert data in to mysql database table which contain mediumtext datatype using java

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

I want to insert image into table which contain a field with datatype MEDIUMTEXT. Please can any one tell how to insert mediumtext data

```
psmt=con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO ofvcard (username,vcard) " + "VALUES (?,?)");
psmt.setString(1,"admin");
fis=new FileInputStream(image);
psmt.setBinaryStream(2, (InputStream)fis, (int)(image.length()));
int s = psmt.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: what happens to the above code ? Any errors?

Comment: Incorrect string value: '\x89PNG\x0D\x0A...' for column 'vcard' at row 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

psmt=con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO ofvcard (username,vcard) " + "VALUES (?,?)");
psmt.setString(1,"admin");
pstmt.setString(2,"testing")
int s = psmt.executeUpdate();

Answer (score 3):

As documented under [The `BLOB` and `TEXT` Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/blob.html):

> `BLOB` values are treated as binary strings (byte strings). They have no character set, and sorting and comparison are based on the numeric values of the bytes in column values. `TEXT` values are treated as nonbinary strings (character strings). They have a character set, and values are sorted and compared based on the collation of the character set.

Therefore your image file (which is *binary*, not *character*, data) may be hitting some encoding issues when byte sequences which are not valid in the column's character set are encountered.

You *could* instead use the `MEDIUMBLOB` type, but really one should store files in a filesystem (which is a database designed specifically for that purpose) and simply store the respective filesystem paths in MySQL.